# Are Snow Leopard text substitutions scriptable?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-snow-leopard, applescript

I prefer using typographical quotation marks when possible, so I love the Smart Quotes part of Snow Leopard’s text replacement feature. But there are a few cases in which I need to toggle it, and it’s a pain to do so from the contextual menu when I’m typing.

Is there any way (preferably via AppleScript, but I can deal with other suggestions) to toggle specific types of text replacement for the frontmost text-input control? And if so, what’s a good way to assign it to a globally-accessible keyboard shortcut (via 3rd-party app if necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to the menu item *Edit » Substitutions » Smart Quotes* via *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Application Shortcuts*.

[image]

The menu item title should be unique enough that this works in (almost) all applications. Screenshot of TextEdit after defining this:

[image]